# Find a string between a character and a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string : http://www.mywebsite/456754567/531613490.htm?menu=contact

I want to get the value between "/" and ".htm". Here : 531613490

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( preg_match('~[^/]+(?=\.htm)~', $string, $matches) ) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Here's a demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/5kjEj6

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how flexible you want your script to be, but here's my try:

- It always takes the last part of the path
- It won't fail for `http://www.mywebsite/456754567.htm/531613490.htm?menu=contact'` as Joseph Silber's solution does.

```
<?php

$path = parse_url('http://www.mywebsite/456754567/531613490.htm?menu=contact', PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathParts = explode('/', $path);
$fullFilename = array_pop($pathParts);

// better use something like lastIndexOf(), this won't fail for 'xxx.abc.htm'
$filename = substr($fullFilename, 0, strpos($fullFilename, '.'));
var_dump( $filename );
```